# HTML5 Video: full screen without borders?

Tags: css, html, html5-video, fullscreen, margin

I would like to show a video inside a web browser, in full screen using HTML5 tags.

Here my online test, that you can run and see the source code:

http://rospo.altervista.org

My problem is that I am unable to avoid margins (blank borders), 
in other words I can't obtain a real FULL SCREEN

In the screeenshot here below I show the unwanted margins:

[image: screenshot]

Any idea to get a full-full-screen ? :-)

BTW, double clicking on the image 
I get finally a real full screen but I think in this case come in the game thge flash player, isn't it ? The point is that i would like to visualize the full screen video also froma a smart/phone/tablet browser (without any flash player ....)

Many thanks!
giorgio

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the HTML in your page *and if it doesn't contain any PHP coding with markup*, then I would suggest you make the body margin to zero

**CSS**

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

I believe in your css you have the page `body` with `8px` `margin`.

---

**UPDATE after the PO comment in this answer**

to get the scroll bar out, you need to modify the `height` property value in you inline style of your `<video>` markup in this line

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" controls="" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

the line should be

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" controls="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

I believe this should solve this *precise* problem.

---

**P.S. general advice:** always separate your style from your HTML in an external `.css` file to make it easy for you to change and update the look and feel of your website.

Comment: Yes, browsers add a `margin: 8px;` on `body`. The OP only needed to inspect his page.

Comment: @Solyaris please update your link http://rospo.altervista.org  too so we can give it a look or you can share the html and css with us using jsfiddle.net

Comment: done. I updated [here](http://rospo.altervista.org) ant it behave correctly (thanks). I have now a minor point: the video is not fully viewed vertically (my PC have resolution: 1366 X 768) and I got a right sidebar

Comment: thanks SULTAN, unfortunately your suggestion to set height: 100%; do not bring the expected behaviour, in that way I get the video just "centered" with a left margin a right margin, see: [screenshot](http://rospo.altervista.org/bordi-3.jpg)